# Mimic the structure of a module that uses module.exports

Tags: javascript, data-structures, module, mocking, jestjs

I have a module that I imported from NPM. Essentially, its structure is as follows:

```
module.exports = function a() {
  return 'a';
};

module.exports.b = function b() {
  return 'b';
};
```

Resulting in the following structure, when printed to the console: `{ [Function: a] b: [Function: b] }`.

How can I mimic this structure, without using `module.exports`? I need this, so that I can mock it in Jest.

I tried the following, but none of these worked:

```
const a = {
  function() {
    return 'a';
  },

  b() {
    return 'b';
  },
};
```

Resulting in: `{ function: [Function: function], b: [Function: b] }`

And:

```
function A() {
  this.b = function b() {
    return 'b';
  };

  return 'a';
}
```

Resulting in: `[Function: A]`

I also tried a few other methods, but the above two seemed the most promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module.exports` is just a variable, so you can follow the library code exactly, but assign into the variable of your choice:

```
const a = function() {
     return 'a';
}
a.b = function() {
    return 'b';
}
```

Comment: Excellent thanks, I didn't know you could do this. I can't think of any situation where it would have been needed - except for now, when I'm trying to mimic the structure of an existing module, to test it. Thanks!